# I somehow disabled all USB ports on my PC through “Device Manager.” What can I do to fix this?

Tags: windows, usb, bios, device-manager

Somehow I accidentally disabled all USB ports through the “Device Manager.” So I've lost mouse and keyboard.

My motherboard is an ASUS Z170-A.

When I restart the machine I can get into BIOS where I have mouse and keyboard. At the BIOS level, all USB ports are enabled. But as soon as I continue into Windows, they become disabled again.

**Edit**: Since I do not have access to a PS/2 mouse or keyboard, I have decided to try to remote into the machine since it's on the same network. I have it's IP address.  I shouldn't have to open any ports if I'm trying to RDP from within the same network, right?

Comment: See if you can use a wired keyboard with a PS/2 connector to bypass USB.  See also if you can remote into the system from another computer and enable USB that way.

Comment: I have no PS/2 peripherals.  So I'm working on RDP into the machine now.  I don't know the name of the computer so I'm trying to figure that out first.

Comment: If you can get in via RDP then your are on a good track!

Comment: If you can find the IP address (IP Scanner) then you can RDP in that way.

Comment: RDP knows what port so I just enter the IP address. You do need to enable remote access in Computer Properties - remote tab.  That is not default so then RDP may not work.

Comment: In theory all you need to do is edit the registry “offline” and remove the disabled flag on the devices in question. Unfortunately I cannot research a complete answer on this right now.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you could get or borrow PS/2 mouse and keyboard,
instead of the ones that use the disabled USB ports.

This will enable you to enter the Device Manager and undo the problem.

Otherwise, you might need to do the heavy operation of
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I am not sure how one can do the Windows 10 Repairs without a keyboard.

Comment: @John: The keyboard will work in the boot media.

Comment: When I use these tools, USB has to be working and no USB works.  @CrazyPaste - please let us know.

Comment: @John: You're wrong - this is a Windows problem. Booting from a boot media does not use the Windows version on the disk.

Comment: I asked the OP to comment if booting from a boot media would work. Perhaps from a cold start.

Comment: Harry - I was not certain. Also I did not downvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

Some computers will have a BIOS setting for emulating a PS/2 keyboard and mouse to the OS from USB.  This means a USB keyboard and mouse look like "legacy" PS/2 devices to Windows (or whichever OS) and bypasses the need for USB drivers.  This was fairly common during the time PS/2 ports were disappearing from computers but on newer systems there may simply be the assumption that there's no need to add the circuits needed for this.  It's no surprise that the BIOS sees the keyboard but Windows does not, the BIOS isa separate simple OS on a ROM and so driver issues on Windows will not affect it.

Some possible hardware fixes:

- Buy a PS/2 keyboard and mouse.  This assumes the presence of PS/2 ports, or willingness to buy an add-on card with PS/2 ports.  A USB to PS/2 adapter will not help, the PS/2 keyboard will look like USB to the operating system.
- Buy a new USB card.  I'm guessing that a new USB card with a chip different than that currently in the computer will load different drivers and be functional.  If not then you still have more USB ports, maybe faster USB ports, maybe USB-C.
- Try a serial mouse.  I've discovered that Windows retained the ability to detect and use a serial mouse long after they've lost popularity, just by plugging it in a serial port Windows will load the drivers and make it work.  This won't give you a keyboard but may be enough to poke around enough to get some keyboard function for a complete fix.  There's add-on cards for adding serial ports if there's no serial port already.  USB to serial adapters won't help.  If you have an older mouse lying around then it may be serial compatible, but you'd have had to keep the adapter that came with it to plug it in a serial port.  "Gaming" mice are most likely to have this feature today for the belief that serial mice are "faster" than USB mice.

The BIOS option for legacy keyboard and mouse support would be the first place I look for a fix, it costs nothing and is easy to enable and disable.  Mentions of RDP were made in other answers and comments and that is another cheap and easy solution to try.  The goal is of course to get some means to get keyboard and mouse input that does not rely on the USB ports, and there's hardware options for that.